# Mapping row values of one CSV to the header values of another CSV and writing a new CSV file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, python-3.7, opencsv

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv

data=np.loadtxt(open("ff.csv","rb"),delimiter=",",dtype=np.str)
print(data)

data1=np.loadtxt(open("x.csv","rb"),delimiter=",",dtype=np.str)
print(data1)

for i in range(1,len(data)):
    
    for j in range(len(data1[0])):
        
        if data[i] == data1[0][j]:
            print(data[i],",",data1[0][j])
        
            column = pd.read_csv("x.csv",usecols=[data1[0][j]])
            print(column)
```

[This is first csv data name is in row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPWT4.png)

[here data is in columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdXBf.png)

I want to match row name with column name and save it into new csv according to match with row

[output what I want here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nprmf.png)

Comment: Please do not use links to image, but post the data as text in the question itself to allow other to copy and paste it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas is a useful tool here - you can pull your column names into a list, pass that list to your second sheet of data as a subset of columns to pull, and then save that dataframe to a new file.

```
data=pd.read_csv("ff.csv", header = 0)

data1=pd.read_csv("x.csv", header = 0)

column_list = data['Name'].to_list()
column_list.append('class')

data1[column_list].to_csv("newfile.csv",index=False)
```